# How to offer money to an open source project?

Tags: open-source, github, etiquette

There's an open source project on GitHub that is very useful, but doesn't have a feature I want and which a fair number of other users have been clamoring for in the issues.

There's already an advanced discussion of the issue, and I get the impression that `good_enough` is pretty feasible, it's just stalled because `perfect` is complicated, and `good_enough !== perfect`.

The Right™ way to go would be to to absorb the discussion, add the feature, present a pull request, address the critiques and polish it for contribution. In this case it's outside my core focus.

It's a utility library, developed for actual work not just for games, so an alternative way might be to offer to sponsor that feature with money. But that doesn't seem like the done thing, can't find any examples. Could try hiring this out but the best people for it seem like those already thinking about it.

What's a polite way to proceed?  Or just wait and see if the feature gets added organically?

Comment: Maybe paying someone who is not involved in this discussion at all is more appropriate, offer that resulting patch to the community and use the fruits of the patch for yourself as long as you need it. be pragmatic. The risk is that it is not adopted, but you will have the feature and others too. Your life is to short to wait ....

Comment: The history of a Git project contains the email addresses of all contributors – you can contact them and ask if they'd be interested in a grant for implementing certain functionality. If possible, try to go through the project's coordinator with this. Offering grants is a pretty nice way to support FOSS projects. If you hire an external developer to implement a feature, remember that you'll also be paying them to get familiar with the code base etc.. This is not necessary if you target the right people already inside the core community.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I believe the best option would be to out-source the work (perhaps on [Freelancer](https://www.freelancer.com/) or something along those lines) so that **you personally** have the features you desire.

Thereafter you can offer the patch back to the community, and it'll be their decision whether or not to adopt it. At the end of the day, this solution will be functional for you as an individual.